# "Did" in affirmative sentences

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, verb-forms

(English is not my native language.) Is the sentence 'only then did she *realised* the sun was setting.' correct? Or should I write 'only then did she *realise* the sun was setting.'? Is 'did' even correct at all in this sentence?

Comment: Only then did she realise the sun was setting.  Because you conjugated *did* and *realise* is in the infinitive.

Comment: The plain form "realise" is required because the dummy auxiliary verb "do" requires a bare infinitival clause as complement.